# IBM BPM GEX (General Exception Handler) Toolkit

Tags: ibm-bpm

I am new to IBM BPM tool , I am not sure how to use GEX toolKit in ibm bpm 8.6 .
Could anyone please guide me how to upgrade GEX toolkit of 8.5.7 to GEX toolkit of 8.6.0.

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have a working GEX on 857 then upgrading to 86 should be a matter of opening the toolkit in PD/WebPD and then updating System and coaches toolkits to latest v8.6. That should be it. It should also work as is in 86 if it worked in 857 without even updating the system toolkits but it's a best practice to do so anyway.
Now with regards to how to use it - well, it was a community wiki asset before. That BPM community wiki no longer exists, it was demolished. But some of the assets were moved over to IBM developerworks like this one. 
You may find examples and documentation that is 3 years old though here - 
https://git.ng.bluemix.net/IBMBPMCommunity/bpm-general-toolkits/tree/master/GEX%20-%20General%20Exception%20Handler%20Toolkit